# Authentication using Jwt and nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, vue.js, jwt

I am having two issues.

1.when I am trying to perform authentication using JWT token and Nodejs I am able to log in and log out but when I logged in if I refresh the page the navbar disappears.

2. when I am not logged in in the login page I gave a link to the registration page when I click that it is not redirecting to that page. This is happening when I don't give the nav bar to authenticate.

This is Login page

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                <form v-on:submit.prevent="login">
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                    <a href="/register">New User? Register here</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'
import EventBus from './EventBus'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
export default {
  components: {Navbar},
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    login () {
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/login',
        {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }).then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''
        if (res) {
        this.emitMethod()
        router.push({ name: 'profile' })
        } 
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err, alert('User doesnot exist'))

      })
    },
    emitMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the script I am using for logout

```
logout () {
      localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    }
```

User routes

```
const express = require("express")
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require("cors")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")

const User = require("../model/User")
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date()
    const userData = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        city: req.body.city,
        cycle: req.body.cycle,
        created: today
    }

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    userData.password = hash
                    User.create(userData)
                        .then(user => {
                            res.json({ status: user.email + ' registered' })
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            res.send('error: ' + err)
                        })
                })
            } else {
                res.json({ "error": 'User already exists' })

            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
})

users.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                    let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: 1440
                    })
                    res.send(token)
                }
            } else {
                res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).json({ error: err })

        })
})

users.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], process.env.SECRET_KEY)

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            userId: decoded.userId
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            res.json(user)
        } else {
            res.send('User does not exist')
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

users.put("/:userId", (req, res) => {
        if (!req.body.firstName,
            !req.body.lastName,
            !req.body.city,
            !req.body.cycle,
            !req.body.biography) {
            res.status(400)
            res.json({
                error: "Bad Data"
            })
        } else {
            User.update(
                { firstName: req.body.firstName,
                  lastName: req.body.lastName,
                  city: req.body.city,
                  cycle: req.body.cycle,
                  biography: req.body.biography
                },
                { where: { userId: req.params.userId } }
            )
            .then(() => {
               res.send("Contact updated")
            })
            .error(err => res.send(err))
        }
    })

module.exports = users
```

Comment: When you receive the JWT from the server, you will need to store it somewhere on the user's machine. Usually this would be done using LocalStorage API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). 

Then, when you do your authentication check on page load, first check to see if the JWT exists in local storage. If it does, then verify that it is valid.

Comment: Ya @djheru I am saving the token using local storage I also posted the code for login log out and my user routes code in the question that I posted can you look at that and let me know if there is something I am doing wrong

Comment: @djheru would it be better to store the token in vuex state, or can state be accessed from outside?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the web app you are building is just for fun or you are planning to use it in production, if so I will suggest you not to use localStorage to save the token. A JWT needs to be stored in a safe place inside the user's browser.

If you store it inside localStorage, it's accessible by any script inside your page (which is as bad as it sounds as an XSS attack can let an external attacker get access to the token).

Don't store it in local storage (or session storage). If any of the 3rd part scripts you include in your page gets compromised, it can access all your users' tokens.

The JWT needs to be stored inside an HttpOnly cookie, a special kind of cookie that's only sent in HTTP requests to the server, and it's never accessible (both for reading or writing) from JavaScript running in the browser.

Source:

1. https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens
2. https://logrocket.com/blog/jwt-authentication-best-practices/
3. https://blog.usejournal.com/sessionless-authentication-withe-jwts-with-node-express-passport-js-69b059e4b22c

Now going back to the original question, I see

```
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
```

But I don't you use it in the template, also can you post the vue component in which you are having issues with?

Comment: You make a very good point about not putting sensitive information in a JWT, but if they are using an SPA that is not being served by an application server, then httpOnly token is not an option. In that case you would need to use localStorage similar to how it is described here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs#handle-authentication-tokens.

Comment: When using httpOnly cookies, the server will automatically send the cookie along with the request, therefore there is no need to save it